# MySQL Allow User use of WHERE but deny SELECT

Tags: mysql

I created a User that has privileges to Select the column username and the column ip. Also he has rights for INSERT and UPDATE for column ip.

My Problem is that he should be able to do the following:

[1] `UPDATE table SET ip='localhost'  WHERE key = "XXXXXXXX"`

but should be denied to do:

[2] `SELECT key from table`

If I give him SELECT rights for column key hey can do [2], if I revoke the rights I get:

```
SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'localhost' for column 'key' in table 'table'
```

Is there something I can do to fix that?

Comment: Even if you could, you couldn't prevent `SELECT key FROM table WHERE key LIKE '%'`...

Comment: You could create a stored procedure the user has rights to execute, without other explicit `UPDATE` or `SELECT` permissions.

Comment: Is it okay if you expressly limit queries to those defined in a stored procedure, or do you need to be able to allow arbitrary queries to modify the `ip` column?

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelBerowski Your tip with the stored procedure was great.
I created the following procedure and it works great.
I only had to give him rights to execute this procedure but he doesn't need Select,update,insert permissions anymore.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_ip(  
IN p_ip varchar(15),  
IN p_key varchar(50)) 
BEGIN 
UPDATE table SET ip = p_ip WHERE key = p_key;  
END
```

Comment: A `View` might be a better choice